# blank window with query of permissions

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I use js sdk for login my site with facebook. If user go to my site first time and try login, it work fine. If user is logged into facebook and go to my site, it work fine too. But if user is logged out from facebook and my site and go to my site after click login button he see popup window and input their email and pass for facebook. After he click login it show blank popup window with [this url](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=189221317879406&redirect_uri=http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=11#cb=f39557df7423a7e&origin=http%253A%252F%252Fintalix.home%252Ff200a2e5499adba&domain=intalix.home&relation=opener&frame=f9306257bd1f0a&sdk=joey&display=popup&response_type=token,signed_request&domain=intalix.home&perms=user_photos,friends_photos,user_birthday,friends_birthday,user_education_history,friends_education_history,user_location,friends_location,user_relationships,friends_relationships,user_work_history,friends_work_history&fbconnect=1&from_login=1&client_id=189221317879406).

I can't understand why it request permission if facebook know that this user is authorized for my site.

here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({ appId: 189221317879406, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth:true });
        };
        (function () {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        } ());  
        function loginWithFacebook(){
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    //FB.api('/me', function(response) {alert(response.name);});
                    window.location.href='http://mysite.com/home/';
                }
            },
            {scope: 'user_photos,friends_photos,user_birthday,friends_birthday,user_education_history,friends_education_history,user_location,friends_location,user_relationships,friends_relationships,user_work_history,friends_work_history'}); 
        } 
    </script>
    <a href="#" onclick="loginWithFacebook()">
            <img src="/files/images/facebook-login-button.png" style="width: 90px; height: 90px;"></a>
</body>
```

Comment: Adding the parameter `show_error=1` to the URL you mentioned brings the good old *“API Error Code: 191 – API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application”* – please research for yourself how to fix this, because it’s been discussed over and over (and over) and over again already.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong in code. There neccessary add option - channelURL: '//site.com/channel.php'
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#channel